# What are some nice matrix representations of $E_6$?

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, root-systems

I'm planning on doing some SAGE computations to play around with the Lie group $E_6$ (not sure which isogeny class yet), and was wondering if anyone knew of some nice matrix representations of the Lie algebra $E_6$.  It's fine if it's huge size matrices, as long as I'm able to "see" the maximal toral algebra and the positive/negative root spaces.

Comment: Surely Sage should already have an implementation of E6...

Comment: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/lie.html has a lot of info on what Sage can do in this area.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to cover what I want to do.  I'm interested in working with the $\operatorname{GL}_6$-like parabolic inside $E_6$, doing some computations with the unipotent radical, seeing when certain elements lie in the big cell, that kind of thing

Comment: My opinion is that the best representation for your purposes is the adjoint one, because a standard parabolic with Levi subgroup GL_6 is precisely the stabilizer of a line there. For calculation is the Lie algebra your can consult Vavilov's paper "Do it yourself structure constants for Lie algebras of types E_l", available for free here: http://www.mathnet.ru/links/abfac179ab51d9903d18ade91caa37bb/znsl1489.pdf